# Can an Indian National Travel to Shenzhen with a Chinese Visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, beijing, shenzhen

Can I (an Indian National) travel with Chinese single entry tourist visa to Shenzhen as well as Beijing in a single trip? Like, Bangalore (India) to Shenzhen, then stay in Shenzhen for two days, then from Shenzhen to Beijing and then stay there for some days, and then back to Bangalore (India) from Beijing. Or do I need a sepearte Shenzhen visa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that.

You have a single-entry visa from China. That visa allows you to enter China one time. Both Shenzen and Bejing are in China. Your trip, therefore, is a single entry into China, some traveling between Shenzen and Beijing within China, then exiting China to return to India.

[A visa on arrival for Shenzen only can be obtained for travelers who are going to Shenzen by land from Hong Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#Special_Economic_Zone_visa_on_arrival), but that doesn't apply to you as you have a regular visa.

Comment: Remember that with a single entry visa, you can't exit China and return (not even to Hong Kong/Macau/Taiwan which have different immigration schemes and are considered exiting China for the purpose of your visa), so you have to visit all your cities in China with domestic flights.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Or by train!

Comment: @David "A visa on arrival for Shenzen is required for travelers who are only going to Shenzen, but that limit shouldn't apply to you as you have a regular visa and are going on to Bejing." Misleading wording: if you have a regular Chinese visa it's not like you can't fly into Shenzhen, only visit Shenzhen and then fly home. That is what the wording implies.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Crazydre, your comment contains too many negatives and I don't understand. Can you rephrase your comment? If my Answer is incorrect or misleading, how might it be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: @David what he is trying to say is that a china visa holder do not need a Shenzhen on arrival visa as long as their china visa is valid for entry